# How do you install LibPuzzle C Library on Media Temple DV server?

Tags: php, mediatemple

I'm unfamiliar with installing extensions/libraries to servers. My question is how do you install Libpuzzle on a Media Temple DV server?

LibPuzzle: http://libpuzzle.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle/doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are directions at the libpuzzle site. Did you try them? I just installed it as a PHP extension on my DV box with no issues. http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/misc/libpuzzle/doc/README-PHP

Comment: @David, Thanks for your response. At the time of posting this I was entirely unfamiliar with installing anything to the server. I've spent some time consulting with someone familiar with server stuff and I should be able to do it now.

Comment: Do I need to install the library first, then install the php extension? Or just install the php extension?

Comment: Install the library for PHP, then enable it as a PHP extension. If you follow the directions I linked step by step it should work fine. Unaccepted? ;D

Comment: @David, I've read the directions numerous times but I think I'm understanding now. I was also reading this doc http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/misc/libpuzzle/doc/README which is where I'm coming from with "install the library first, then install the php extension". However, by enable the extension, you mean enabling it in php.ini correct?

Comment: @David: Also it looks like I'm getting a "cannot find config.m4".  My guess is because I'm placed the libpuzzle folder in the wrong location. Where would be the best place to put it on the server to install from?

Comment: The answer to this problem has been solved thanks to Media Temple.

Comment: @stwhite Did you resolve weather or not libpuzzle needs to be in a specific location when installing?